# first and last methods used excluded items

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

i used `last()` to get last item of queryset after exclude some items as below:

```
holidays = HolidayModel.objects.all().values_list('date', flat=True)
result = BorseExchangeLog.objects.exclude(
hint_time__date__in=holidays
)
# output 1
print(list(result.valuse_list('hint_time__date',flat=True).distinct('hint_time__date')))
#output2
print(result.last().hint_time.date())
```

but in `output2` print item that not exists in `output1`

i test some other codes as below:

```
print(list(logs.values_list('hint_time__date',flat=True).distinct('hint_time__date')))
print(list(logs.values_list('hint_time__date', flat=True).distinct('hint_time__date'))[-1])
print(logs.order_by('hint_time__date').last().hint_time.date())


[..., datetime.date(2020, 10, 21), datetime.date(2020, 10, 26)]
2020-10-26
2020-10-25
```

my holiday model:

```
class HolidayModel(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey('accounts.Account', on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name=_('Creator'))
    reason = models.CharField(default='', max_length=200, verbose_name=_('Reason'))
    date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now, verbose_name=_('Date'))
```

and other model is :

```
class BorseExchangeLog(models.Model):
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    hint_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

i test that by `first()` and problem was there too

what is problem? my code is wrong or bug from django orm?

using django2.2 and postgresql

Comment: Can you add the output you get and the models to your question?

Comment: ok post edited. add some examples and other thing i tested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your datetimes are timezone aware but the `date()` method on datetime objects does not take the timezone into account, `__date` will take the timezone into account [provided your DB supports it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#database-time-zone-definitions). Use the [`django.utils.timezone.localdate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.localdate) function to get a date taking into account the timezone

```
from django.utils.timezone import localdate
print(localdate(result.last().hint_time))
```